# Detect IMU using i2cdetect

Tags: ubuntu, i2c

First of all, sorry for my English and limited ubuntu knowledge as I'm quite new to this OS.

I'm having a 9DOF(https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10724) IMU connectting to my fit-pc(ubuntu 12.04) directly through the usb-iss(http://www.tinyosshop.com/index.php?...product_id=645) and NOT THROUGH THE ARDUINO. The problem I have is that when I use i2cdetect, it only can detect the address of the Gyroscope(working) chip but for the Accelerometer and Magnetometer it can't detect. Especially for the Accelerometer, when I used i2cdetect only for the first time after booting, it could detect it's address and I could not access to the Accelerometer using i2cdetect -y -0 0x53.

I have done instantiating the devices using " echo ADXL345 0x53 > ...." but still not response from the accelerometer. For the Magnetometer, totally not response from it.

So I'm wondering is there any solution to get my ubuntu detect or the 3 addresses? Or is there any sample code(C,C++) for this?

Thank you and have a nice day